# Solr index values of Cassandra Map type

Tags: solr4, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have a Cassandra table that contains a Map type.   I want to create a Solr index that will allow me to search all the values in the Map (ignoring the keys).   I have been successful at doing this with a Set type and was hoping there would be a way to do the same thing for a Map.

Here is an example.

`CREATE TABLE company (id text PRIMARY KEY, name text, user_phones map<text,text>);`

`INSERT INTO company (id, name, user_phones) values ('1', 'Joes Construction', {'userid_52':'1-333-444-5555', 'userid_17':'1-333-222-4444'});`

`INSERT INTO company (id, name, user_phones) values ('5', 'Marks Auto', {'userid_7':'1-333-123-4567'});`

I simply want to use the solr index to find the companies with a given phone number -- "user_phones:1333*"

Unfortunately I have not found anything to allow me to do this.   I have read this page - [Mapping of Solr types](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html) and this page - [Using Dynamic Fields](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/3.2/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchDynFlds.html).   The second page talks about using DynamicFields but this would force me to know what my keys in the map will look like and in my case all my keys will be unique.  If I had a way to simply extract the values of a map and copy them to field I would do it.  Unfortunately I have not figured out how to do this.

Is there any way to effectively search the values of a Cassandra map in Solr?

I am using Cassandra 2, Solr 4, DataStax 4.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is using a non-stored multivalued copy field, and set the dynamic pattern as the source field to copy from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields)

Comment: Thanks, this does work.   It feels a little hacky though.   In order for this to work all of my keys must be prepended with the same string such as "user_id_123".

Answer (score 1):

You can go with two approaches:

1) Try with Transformer in **dataconfig.xml**

```
< entity name="Entity" transformer="RegexTransformer" Query="........>

< field column="user_phones" splitBy="}"   />

< /entity>
```

Now you can search " user_phones: * 1333 * " It will bring your expected output. :)

2) Please try with `<script>..... </script>` in dataconfig.xml.

Cassandra Integration with Solr.  [here](http://bigdatatutor.blogspot.ae/)

Comment: I tried adding this code to my config.xml but I can't seem to get it to work.   I am using a config similar to the one specified here - http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTutStrt.html

Comment: Please can you attach the Cassandra table structure and dataconfig.xml which you tried.